I baked the data for my smoke simulation but the smoke isn't showing up in the viewpart or render. BUT I think the data baked correctly?
I baked the data for my smoke simulation but the smoke isn't showing up. However, the domain appears small and constrained around the dissolve object at the beginning (image 1). After I press play, the domain expands which tells me the data baked correctly (image 2). Images 3 & 4 show the principled volume shaders used for both the domain and dissolve object as recommended by the tutorial I followed. What information am I missing? Why isn't the smoke showing up?
I'm very new to Blender. So I would also appreciate any suggestions of tutorials to look up that would help with this issue.





Delete those cubes and domains you have, make a new simple shape you want the smoke to emit from, press the spacebar and use quick smoke, which should get you started.

Thank you! That works so much better.
